# Are DLLs generally non-ideal for speed critical applications?

Tags: c++, dll

Up until now, I've only ever written and built static libraries, and so, I'm new to the shared library scene, or DLLs, as they are called on Windows.

From what I understand, the key feature of DLLs is that the library code is "loaded" and "unloaded" from the application as it makes calls into library. As such, my question is, does this dynamic loading and unloading (generally) make DLLs non-ideal for speed critical applications?

For example, consider this C++ snippet:

```cpp
int x = 4;
lib_function(x);
non_lib_function();
My_Lib_Type foo(4, 3);
```

Assuming `My_Lib_Type` and `lib_function()` are defined in the DLL, would the application load the library to call `lib_function()`, unload after the call, and then load again to call the constructor for `My_Lib_Type`? If this is how it works, how fast is this switching process?

Comment: That is not how it works. Libraries that are not loaded "by hand" in the application are loaded when the process is loaded. Such libraries are generally not unloaded until the process ends.

Comment: When you load the DLL it becomes part of your process, and any calls you make to it are just like regular calls. There are a few gotchas that you should be aware of, however. Microsoft publishes a useful document on [DLL Best Practices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/dynamic-link-library-best-practices)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A DLL is typically loaded (and unloaded) **only once** by an application: either *implicitly* (if your executable is linked against it, *via* the corresponding export library) or *explicitly* (*via* calls to `LoadLibrary()` and `FreeLibrary()`, on Windows). It is not loaded each time one of its functions is called.

Once that DLL is loaded, its component functions and other exported units are accessed in much the same way as those defined in the executable module itself – the DLL is loaded into the process memory of the calling application.

So, no, there will be no noticeable speed degradation (or there *shouldn't* be) when using a DLL over a statically-linked library.

Comment: If it is incredibly sensitive it might notice the difference between a directly-mapped call and an indirect call. A function call in the same binary can likely apply a fix-up to the actual call instruction while a DLL is going to go through some kind of table.

Comment: @SoronelHaetir Yeah. That could happen when using full optimization, like link-time code generation. But I don't think that was the OP's major concern.